# issue with scraping using beautiful soup and selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to practice using selenium / BS4 and ive ran into an issue.

my code is here
[link to code](https://pastebin.com/8HGjn869)

basically im trying to get a url from:

```
`'class':'td_text_highlight_marker_green td_text_highlight_marker'`
```

but whenever i run the script the returned number of links is always different.

everytime it runs it should return 18.
I even tried to click the link to follow it using selenium and for the life of me i cannot figure it out.

please help :)

Comment: Edit code to your post please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage DOM does not load fully in time for your search. So to ensure the `span` is actually there before you start looking for it with `BeautifulSoup`, add a `WebDriverWait`.

```
for coupon_url in coupon_url_list:
    driver.get(coupon_url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='td_text_highlight_marker_green td_text_highlight_marker']")))
    content = driver.page_source
    # rest of your code here
```